# Are ints always initialized to 0?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, int, instance-variables

Is it safe to count on `int`s always being initialized to 0 in Objective-C?

More specifically, when an object with `int` ivars has been newly instantiated, is it safe to assume that its ivars have value 0?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Yes, class instance variables are always initialized to 0 (or `nil`, `NULL`, or `false`, depending on the exact data type).  See the [Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language](http://web.archive.org/web/20111006112529/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#/web/20111006132944/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW1):

> The `alloc` method dynamically allocates memory for the new object’s instance variables and initializes them all to 0—all, that is, except the `isa` variable that connects the new instance to its class.

---

**EDIT 2013-05-08**
Apple seems to have removed the above document (now linked to The Wayback Machine).  The (currently) active document [Programming With Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html) contains a similar citation:

> The `alloc` method has one other important task, which is to clear out the memory allocated for the object’s properties by setting them to zero. This avoids the usual problem of memory containing garbage from whatever was stored before, but is not enough to initialize an object completely.

---

However, this is *only* true for instance variables of a class; it is also true for POD types declared at global scope:

```
// At global scope
int a_global_var;  // guaranteed to be 0
NSString *a_global_string;  // guaranteed to be nil
```

With one exception, it is *not* true for local variables, or for data allocated with `malloc()` or `realloc()`; it is true for `calloc()`, since `calloc()` explicitly zeros out the memory it allocates.

The one exception is that when Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) is enabled, stack pointers to Objective-C objects are implicitly initialized to `nil`; however, it's still good practice to explicitly initialize them to `nil`.  From the [Transitioning to to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW5):

> Stack Variables Are Initialized with `nil`
>
> Using ARC, strong, weak, and autoreleasing stack variables are now implicitly initialized with `nil`

In C++ (and C++ objects being used in Objective-C++), class instance variables are also *not* zero-initialized.  You must explicitly initialize them in your constructor(s).

Comment: Spot on. However, the fact that people often wonder about this detail can be reason enough to be more explicit about initializing variables, arguably the "safer" choice. Initializing to 0/nil/NULL never hurt anyone... :-)

Comment: I agree with Quinn. In this case, however, I'm creating an "abstract" class which doesn't implement -(void)init, and I don't want to force every subclass to remember to initialize the ivars. So it's good to know that I can count on them being initialized to 0.

Comment: My experience even in release mode for iOS is that even local variables are initialized to 0

Comment: @PsychoDad My experience is the opposite.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Link to official doc is dead. Can you fix that?

Comment: @Pang: Fixed now.  Apple has sadly removed the original "Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language" document AFAICT.

Comment: Under ARC local variables of type `id` are also initialized to nil.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: Do you have a citation/reference for that?

Comment: Apple ARC Release Notes, under Lifetime Qualifiers, subheading: stack variables are initialized with nil - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4

Comment: Does the same apply to `NSUInteger`s / `CGFloat`s ?

Comment: @n00bProgrammer: Yes.  In the situations described above, all variables are "zero-initialized" in whatever manner that means for their respective data types.  Arithmetic types (`int`, `NSUInteger`, `CGFloat`, `float`, `bool`, `BOOL`, `char`, etc.) are all initialized to 0 represented in those types.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you should assume any values for initialization.  If you are building logic around a "0" value, you should set it to be sure.

Comment: I assume we can see this as a valid answer for C++, while Adam's answer applies to Objective-C?

Comment: Adam's answer for Objective C is exactly right - Objective C absolutely guarentees that ivars are set to nil/NULL/false/0 on allocation and it is perfectly sensible to accept and use this fact.  For example, this enables trivial lazy initialization of NSMultableArray* ivars with [NSMultableArray array or new] when they are noticed to be nil.  Combined with Objective C guarentteing [(NSMultableArray*) count] returns 0, you can often defer the initialization even further. Learn to love the way Objective C does it, not just fight against its differences.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, in C global vars are initialized to zero.
In Objective-C even local vars are initialized to zero.
You can count on it.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield's answer directly contradicts your claim that even local vars are initialized to zero. Who is wrong?