# Does an int in Objective-C have a default value of 1?

Tags: objective-c, int, local-variables, variable-initialization

I have this simple line of code:

```
int x;
```

`x` automatically has the value of 1. I don't set it to anything but when I debug, it shows that `x` is 1.

Does an `int` have a default value of 1?!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. `int` has an undefined default value. It just happens to be `1` in this case. It could just as easily be `-18382` or `22` or `0xBAADF00D`.

Always initialize your variables in C.

Answer (score 6):

The initial value is undefined, and in this case will be whatever happened to be in that memory location before `x` started using it.

(Depending on the surrounding code, you might find that in your specific case it's always `1`, but you can't be sure of that.)

Answer (score 5):

No, on the contrary, `x` has no default value at all. What you're seeing is the garbage that the variable was placed upon when you created it.

Answer (score -1):

Instance variables [are initialized to 0](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ObjectAllocation/ObjectAllocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH7-SW1) before your initializer runs..

ref:

- [Are instance variables set to nil by default in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786781/are-instance-variables-set-to-nil-by-default-in-objective-c)

Comment: the question is not about instance variables.