# iPhone maths not quite adding up right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, math, integer

I am adding values held within an array but the sum is +1 what it actually should be.

```
//update totalscore
    uint newTotalScore;

    for (uint i=0; i< [bestscoresArray count] ; i++) {      
        newTotalScore += [[bestscoresArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];  

    }


    totalscore = newTotalScore;
```

//output
l1bestscore=15900, l2bestscore=7800, l3bestscore=81000, l4bestscore=81000, l5bestscore=0, l6bestscore=0, l7bestscore=0, l8bestscore=0, l9bestscore=0, l10bestscore=0, totalscore=185701

As you can see the totalscore output is 185701 but the sum of all values is 185700.

Would anyone have any ideas why this is occurring?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must define `newTotalScore`'s initial value:

```
uint newTotalScore = 0;
```

Otherwise it will be undefined. In your case it was `1` but it could have been any other value.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about this, but did you try initializing `newTotalScore` to zero? (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990817) about variable initialization.) If that does not help, give us more code.