# Why is my code working with me initializing NSInteger?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, nsinteger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(Objective-)C ints always initialized to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990817/objective-c-ints-always-initialized-to-0)

I have an interface

```
@interface MyInterface
{
   NSInteger _count;
}

@end
```

Then in my implementation I am just using is as

```
if (_count==0)
{
  //do somthing
}
_count++;
```

And it works i.e. the first time around when this is executed the value is in fact 0 even though I never initialized it to be zero.

Is it because the default value of NSInteger is 0?

Comment: When an Objective-C class is instantiated, all the instance variables are set to their initial values. It's done by the allocation mechanism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you meant to write `==` instead of `=`, the answer is that all of the instance variables (ivars) of an Objective-C class get initialized to 0 or `nil` when the object gets created.  See the question [(Objective-)C ints always initialized to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990817/objective-c-ints-always-initialized-to-0).

If you actually wrote `if (_count = 0)` with a single `=`, then that's not doing what you expected -- it's assigning 0 to `_count`, and then testing if it's non-zero (the expression `if (x)` tests if `x` is non-zero).  Since you just assigned 0 to it, it's not non-zero, so the test will always fail.

Answer (score 1):

change your if statement to

```
if (_count == 0)
```

remember double equals is comparison, single equals is assignment

Answer (score 1):

you are using

```
if (_count=0)
```

this will set value `0` to variable `_count`, and if this action success, code between `{}` is executed

to test value of variable use comparison operator **`==`**

```
if(_count == 0)
```