# Why is the instance variable (apparently) not set to nil by init?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, instance-variables

I understand that in Objective C 'instance variables are always initialized to 0 (or nil, NULL, or false, depending on the exact data type)'. [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990817/objective-c-ints-always-initialized-to-0)

In the unit test2 below, why is the instance variable `_willBeRipeBy` in the orange instance of `Fruit` not set to `nil`? It fails at `STAssertNil([orange willBeRipeBy],nil)`.

`test2` passes if I create an `init` method to explicitatly set `_willBeRipeBy` to nil or if I rename `test1` to test3 to change the execution order.

Creating `apple` in `test1` seems to be effecting the memory that `orange` uses but why is Fruits `init` not resetting the instance variable to nil.

I am new to objective C, Thanks.

(using Xcode 4.3, iOS5.0 with Automatic Reference Counting on)

```
@interface Fruit : NSObject
- (NSDate *)getWillBeRipeBy;
- (void)setWillBeRipeBy:(NSDate *)ripeBy;
@end

@implementation Fruit

NSDate *_willBeRipeBy;

- (NSDate *)getWillBeRipeBy{
    return _willBeRipeBy;
}
- (void)setWillBeRipeBy:(NSDate *)ripeBy{
    _willBeRipeBy = ripeBy;
}
@end

@implementation TestIvarInitialisationTests

- (void)test1
{
    Fruit *apple = [[Fruit alloc] init];
    STAssertNil([apple getWillBeRipeBy],nil);
    NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
    [apple setWillBeRipeBy:now];
    STAssertEqualObjects([apple getWillBeRipeBy], now,nil);
}

- (void)test2
{
    Fruit *orange = [[Fruit alloc] init];
    STAssertNil([orange getWillBeRipeBy],nil);
}
@end
```

Comment: Don't prefix methods with `get`, btw.  Just call it `willBeRipeBy` or `ripeDate` or `willBeRipeDate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare the variable as an instance variable inside the header file or in `{}`-brackets after the `@implementation` directive.

Your implementation is a global variable

btw. you shouldn't name methods like "get..." - this is against cocoa naming conventions. You should only use "get.." when you want to set a non-object type with unknown size, e.g.: `CGRect rect; [userInfoDictionary getValue:&rect forKey:@"bla"]`

you can use properties (`@property(strong) NSString *property` and `@synthesize property`) to auto-implement instance variables along with getter and setter methods

Answer (score 2):

Because variables declared inside the implementation block are not instance variables, they are globals shared between class instances. And apparently globals are not guaranteed to be initialized to a sane value.

Your Fruit class should look like this:

```
@interface Fruit : NSObject
@property(strong) NSDate *willBeRipeBy;
@end

@implementation Fruit
@synthesize willBeRipeBy;
@end
```